# Is it possible to set cron for 10:01?

Tags: cron

Right now I have `0 22 * * *`, but my script checks to see if it's between 6 pm and 10 pm, and will not run at exactly 10 pm, can I set cron to run at 10:01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can:

```
1 22 * * * command to execute
```

will do what you need

---

How to setup a cronjob in general:

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

---

**Sidenote**

Special characters in cronjobs

**Asterisk (*)**

The asterisk indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field. E.g., using an asterisk in the 4th field (month) indicates every month.

**Slash ( / )**

Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

**Comma ( , )**

Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

**Hyphen ( - )**

Hyphens define ranges. For example, 2000-2010 indicates every year between 2000 and 2010 AD, inclusive.

**Percent ( % )**

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % are sent to the command as standard input.

---

Source of explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: True story, added it! @BaconBits